# Homology groups of one-point compactification of $(\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\})/\sim$

Tags: algebraic-topology, compactification

I tried to solve an exercise of algebraic topology. Let $X$ be $(\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\})/\sim$, where $x\sim y$ means $x=y$ or $x=-y$. The question is finding homology groups of (Alexandroff) one-point compactification of   $X$.

I think X is homotopy equivalence to the real projective plane $RP^2$.  But $RP^2$ is compact, so I think one-point compactification of X is also $RP^2$. Then one-point compactification is meaningless. Am I wrong something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT 1** :
One-point compactification $Z$ of $X$ is strictly same to the Thom space of the trivial line bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^2$. So we have:
\begin{equation}
H_i(Z;\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{i-1}(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})\ (i \neq0),
H_0(Z;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}.
\end{equation}

**EDIT 2** :
We can calculate the homology group by using an elementary Mayer-Vietoris argument without using any Thom isomorphism as follows.
Let $M$ be a compact space and $X:=M\times\mathbb{R}$ (in the case of your question, $M=\mathbb{R}P^2$) . Now we want to calculate the homology group of one-point compactification $Z=X\cup\{\infty\}$. We have an open covering $\{U+,U-\}$ where $U_{+}:=M\times(-1,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}$ and $U_{-}:=M\times(-\infty,1)\cup\{\infty\}$. Note that $U_{\pm}$ are contractible and $U_+\cap U_-$ is homotopy equivalent to $M\sqcup\{\infty\}$. Using Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence, we have $\tilde H_i(Z;\mathbb{Z})\cong\tilde H_{i-1}(M\sqcup\{\infty\};\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: "strictly same" means homeomorphic?

Comment: Oops! I mistook the definition of $X$. I edited my answer.

Comment: OK. I understood. But is there a way to find homology groups without a Thom isomorphism? Probably the solution with a Thom space is not assumed. So I want to solve otherwise, for example the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Comment: How about "EDIT 2" answer?

Comment: I see. So $H_2(Z)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},~H_1(Z)\cong H_0(Z)\cong \mathbb{Z}$and$~H_n(Z)=0~(n>2)$. Thank you many times!